# Healthcheck URL automatically taking port 8080 instead of https port 443

Tags: spring-boot

Healthcheck URL automatically taking port 8080 instead of https port 443

I am using below set of properties in config store to register our service in service mesh. The third URL(healthCheckUrl) in below property taking port 8080 automatically. but i want the port as 443. other two urls are taking port as 443. Please advise which property i need so that it will take 443 port

```
eureka.dashboard.path=http://example-22222.apcld-np.xxxx.intranet/actuator/info

eureka.instance.hostname=example-22222.apcld-np.xxxxx.intranet

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=false

eureka.instance.instance-id=example-dev

eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled=false

eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true

server.https.port=443

eureka.instance.securePort=${server.https.port}

eureka.instance.metadataMap.management.port=${server.https.port}

eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.securePort}/actuator/info

eureka.instance.homePageUrl=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.securePort}/actuator/health
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.securePort}/actuator/health

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://registry.abc-dev.xxxxxx.com:8500/eureka

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

Comment: If you want to use https you will need to use the https protocol not the http protocol.

Comment: The URLs are getting registered as  https even though i used http in properties. The problem is with the port for healthCheckUrl  which is taking as 8080 instead of 443.other URLs  statusPageUrl and homePageUrl  taking port as 443.is any other property need to add so that healthCheckUrl also will take port 443?